# Limiting User Permissions

Tags: users

I have 3 sets types of users admins, writers & paid writers. Drupal has a built in administer role but not a limited administer role. I want the paid writer role to control some permissions but not all permissions of writers (like the types of content they can create). Is there a place to do this in Drupal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `admin/people/permissions` set `Administer permissions` for the `paid writer` role:

[image]